# react props not updating with redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I've always used react-redux `connect` to configure props but I need to use a react `Component` to use lifecycle methods. I'm noticing that my props that I'm grabbing from the store seem to be static and they do not update as the store updates.

Code:

```js
class AlertModal extends Component {

  title
  isOpen
  message

  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.context
    const state = store.getState()
    console.log('state', state)
    console.log('store', store)
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => this.forceUpdate())
    this.title = state.get('alertModal').get('alertModalTitle')
    this.isOpen = state.get('alertModal').get('isAlertModalOpen')
    this.message = state.get('alertModal').get('alertModalMessage')
    this.forceUpdate()
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe()
  }

  updateAlertModalMessage(message) {
    this.context.store.dispatch(updateAlertModalMessage(message))
  }
  updateAlertModalTitle(title) {
    this.context.store.dispatch(updateAlertModalTitle(title))
  }

  updateAlertModalIsOpen(isOpen) {
    this.context.store.dispatch(updateAlertModalIsOpen(isOpen))
  }

  render() {

    console.log('AlertModal rendered')
    console.log('AlertModal open', this.isOpen) <======= stays true when in store it is false

    return (
      <View
```

How do I set up `title`, `isOpen`, and `message` so they reflect the store values at all times?

Comment: what is the need of this.forceUpdate() ?

Comment: Just connect your component to redux store using connect. Then use mapStateToProps to get the updated props.

Comment: @Codesingh There is an view further down in the code that uses `onLayout` to get the height of the view. Then it styles content using the height. That's why I need to call `forceUpdate` after it has mounted - because the first render does not have the height.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be something like this. In your Confirmation component:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { modalActive: state.confirmation.modalActive };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Confirmation);
```

In your reducer index file, is should be something like this:

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  confirmation: ConfirmationReducer
});
```

I believe you have your own reducer file called ConfirmationReducer here. It should be something like this.

```js
import { ON_CONFIRM } from '../actions';

const INITIAL_STATE = {modalActive: true};
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case ON_CONFIRM:
      return { ...state, modalActive: action.payload };
  }

  return state;
}
```

Make sure you write your own action creator to create an action with the above type and relevant payload of boolean type.

Finally you should be able to access the property from the store inside your Confirmation component like this:

```js
{this.props.modalActive}
```

You have not posted entire code, so it makes very difficult to give a solution to the exact scenario. Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah the key was I needed to keep using the react-redux `connect` which I had abandoned. The props do not update with the redux store if they're not `connect`ed. Thanks.

Comment: Yes of course, that's where the connect helper or HOC comes in. Anyway I am glad that you made it !

Comment: For my issue it was not realizing that state was divided into the respective reducers. Thanks @RavindraRanwala

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was that I was assigning this.props.myObject to a variable which wasn't deep cloned so I fixed it by using

```
let prev = Object.assign({}, this.props.searchData)
```

What I was doing

```
let prev = this.props.searchData
```

So I was disturbing the whole page.Seems quiet noob on my part.

Comment: Also, it's common mistake to

    `Object.assign(this.props.searchData, newData)`

instead of

    `Object.assign({}, this.props.searchData, newData)`

Answer (score 2):

this may help you

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

 console.log();
 this.setState({searchData : nextProps.searchData})
}
```